# Inner classes: Android vs Java

Tags: java, android

I'm aware that inner classes are not recommended in Android because they hold a reference to the enclosing class. However, in Java, the outer class is only GCed when the inner class is no longer referenced. That means, in Android, provided you have a non-static reference in the outer activity class to the inner class, the inner class cannot exist longer than the outer activity class because the activity can only be destroyed if it doesn't hold a reference to the inner class anymore (at least that is what I'm inferring). So what's the problem using non-static inner classes then (since they can't obviously exist longer than the outer activity if you infer from java)? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you read non-static inner classes are not recommended in Android?

Comment: This is not only an android issue. For interchangeable and fast code you should avoid them except they are static and store the information they require as local fields. The problem with inner classes is that you can not set the reference to the parent class to `null` to get it GC'ed. The compiler has to generate access methods if the parent class members that the inner class access are private and you have one inner class per parent class instance.

Comment: @Cristian scroll to the bottom of this link http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
it is to be avoided if you can't control the inner class life cycle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this simple example

```
class Leaker 
{
    public static Object leakedObj;
}

class MyActivity extends Activity
{
     public class MyInnerClass { ... }

     void onCreate(Bundle savedState) 
     {
        Leaker.leakedObj = new MyInnerClass();
        //The activity now won't be GCed until Leaker.leakedObj is cleared.          
     }
}
```

You can easily pass an inner non-static class outside the context of your activity. As long as you don't pass your inner class to objects outside of your Activity's lifecycle you should be okay. But it certainly IS possible to leak your activity via an inner class.

Comment: thanks justin. your answer seems promising. so just to confirm- can non-static inner classes live longer than an activity if there are no other references to the inner class except for references in the outer activity only, all of which are non-static?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the main problem with non-static inner-classes of Activity: an Activity can fail to be GC'd at the desired time because some third live (non-Activity-lifecycle) object somewhere else is hanging on to a reference to an instance of the inner class, which in turn hangs on to the Activity via synthetic reference.

Comment: @OckhamsRazor, If the only references to your inner class are from the Activity (and they are all non-static), than the Activity will be collected as normal.

Comment: You can think of this is a string graph. Imagine that each reference is a string. So, the Activity has strings running to the inner-class and vice versa. Android also has a main string that is connected to the Activity. Now, once the Android cuts the activity string, both the activity and inner-class detach from the graph and can be collected. In my leak example, however, there still is a string attached to the static Leaker class from the inner-class. So, the string from Leaker->inner-class->Activity still keeps the Activity alive (which is what you don't want).

Answer (score 6):

I won't bother paraphrasing, because Google can explain it better.

Assuming:  Parent class is `Foo` and inner class is `Foo$Inner`:

The problem is that the VM considers direct access to Foo's private members from Foo$Inner     to be illegal because Foo and Foo$Inner are different classes, even though the Java language allows an inner class to access an outer class' private members. To bridge the gap, the compiler generates a couple of synthetic methods:

```
/*package*/ static int Foo.access$100(Foo foo) {
    return foo.mValue;
}
/*package*/ static void Foo.access$200(Foo foo, int value) {
    foo.doStuff(value);
}
```

The inner class code calls these static methods whenever it needs to access the mValue field or invoke the doStuff method in the outer class. What this means is that the code above really boils down to a case where you're accessing member fields through accessor methods. Earlier we talked about how accessors are slower than direct field accesses, so this is an example of a certain language idiom resulting in an "invisible" performance hit.

If you're using code like this in a performance hotspot, you can avoid the overhead by declaring fields and methods accessed by inner classes to have package access, rather than private access. Unfortunately this means the fields can be accessed directly by other classes in the same package, so you shouldn't use this in public API.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PackageInner

Comment: thanks, this is cool stuff. but it still doesn't answer my question- can non-static inner classes live longer than an activity if there are no other references to the inner class except for references in the outer activity, which are non-static?

Comment: @OckhamsRazor You ask "can [instances of] non-static inner classes live longer than an activity if there are no other references to [instances of] the inner class except for [non-static] references in the outer activity?"  The answer is: no.

Comment: ah, cool, thanks mike, you phrased it better. and also thats what i wanted to know. cheers!

Comment: Its also important to note that with the advent of the JIT compiler the performance "penalty" here is most likely negligible.